# xl-deploy: Getting HTTP error code : 500 error

Tags: xl-deploy, deployit

I am getting this error while running "mvn clean xldeploy:import"

```
Failed to execute goal com.xebialabs.xldeploy:xldeploy-maven-plugin:5.1.0:import (default-cli) on project gsp.tms.app: Execution default-cli of goal com.xebialabs.xldeploy:xldeploy-maven-plugin:5.1.0:import failed: Failed : HTTP error code : 500 -> [Help 1]
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

May be checking log file located at XLDeploy server under *"XLD_INSTALL_HOME/log/deployit.log"* at time of executing this gives more details,

This error can happen for multiple reasons for example due to unknown type definition needed by package being imported which could happen because of missing plugin in XLDeploy it self.

Another thing you can do is to try to import this package from XLDeploy UI and see if there are any errors during import.